# How to toggle 2 jQuery functions on one botton(one botton to turn on and off the lamp)

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter

Here is my website made by the framework CodeIgniter,

[my personal website](http://www.littlecode.ymcdesign.com/)

in the first page, when I click on the lamp's botton, I can turn on the light, but I can't turn it off by the same botton, I tried lots of the jQuery function, such as on() and off(), bind() and unbind(), or switch on/off botton, but still I can't tell the computer that:

> once the light is on, you can stop the on function and pass to off function, and then do the same thing reversely.

HTML:

```html
<img id="lampe_lumiere" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/cadre_vide.png') ?>" alt="lampe_lumiere"/>

<map name="lien">
  <a href="lampe_not_jump">
    <area alt="lampe" shape="poly" coords="" href="#lampe_not_jump" />
  </a>
</map>
```

I put the light effect image in the background of the `img` with `opacity 0`,

the lamp's botton is in the `area` inside the `map`

CSS:

```css
#lampe_lumiere{
    top:0;
    opacity:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:-2;
    position:absolute;
    background:url('../../assets/img/lampe_lumiere.png') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* pour anciens Chrome et Safari */
    background-size: cover; /* version standardisée */
}
```

so I tried jQuery like this:

```js
    var $lampe = $('#lampe_lumiere').css('opacity');

    $('area[alt="lampe"]').bind('click', function(event){
        $('#lampe_lumiere').fadeTo('slow', 1);

        if($lampe == 1){
            $( this ).unbind( event );
            $( this ).bind('click', function(event){
                $('#lampe_lumiere').fadeTo('slow', 0);
            });
        }
    });
```

Once I can do this, I will do the same thing to the plant.

Thanks a lot for those who can help me!

Comment: Could you toggle the class 'on' using http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp and then in your css handle when its on or off?

Comment: As you see, Rudi gave me the example which works well, so I take his answer. But still thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate the opacity or any other css property like so:

```
var $lampe = $('#lampe_lumiere');

$lampe.animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 200);
```

200 is the speed in ms.

Example:

```
var $lampe = $('#lampe_lumiere');
var isOn = false;

$('area[alt="lampe"]').on('click', function () {
    $lampe.animate({
        opacity: (isOn ? 0 : 1)
    }, 200);
    isOn = !isOn;
});
```

Comment: YES!!!  I copy your example code, and it works very well, I can now turn on and turn off the lamp! You are my hero, man!!!  I'm a beginner of the web language, I try to understand your code:   at first, you store the lampe_lumiere in a variable, and store the "false" value to the variable isOn.    then, when you click on the "area", animate the lampe_lumiere's opacity from 0 to 1, with the participation of isOn, at the end you change it's value to "true", which means the next click, it will change the side of 0 and 1,  but what is the "?" doing here?    THANK YOU again!

Comment: Hi, glad I could help! The part with the question mark is a short form for if/else. If `isOn` is true, make it 0 otherwise 1. The last line `isOn = !isOn` switches the state from false to true and next time from true to false and so on. Salute!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$('area[alt="lampe"]').bind('click', function(event){


    if($('#lampe_lumiere').css('opacity') == 1){

            $('#lampe_lumiere').fadeTo('slow', 0);
    }else{
       $('#lampe_lumiere').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }
});
```

good luck!!!

Comment: Oh my god, your code works too!!!  Today is my lucky day,  you know what, I will take your code in my js page, too. Your code is based on my code, which means I was almost able to get it done, very glad to know that and very appreciate for your help!!!